# PHP $_SESSION data overwritten after each $_POST

Tags: php, session

I'm sending data over to a PHP file and storing it using `$_SESSION`. I'd like to post multiple instances of data to the session at different times and view these on the front end. Currently I can store one item in my session and this is displayed on the front end, however I'm struggling to add further instances of `artist` and `title` as it simply gets overwritten every time I `$_POST` data across.

How do I store and display an array of `$_POST` data in the session variable? I've tried adding a further set of `[]` after `$_SESSION['artist']` and `$_SESSION['title']` but this doesn't work.

```
<?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_POST['artist']))
   {
      $_SESSION['artist'] = $_POST['artist'];
   }
     if(isset($_POST['title']))
   {
     $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
   }    

     print_r($_SESSION['artist']);
     echo "<br>";
     print_r($_SESSION['title']);
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['title'][] = $_POST['title'];` should work.

Comment: In what way does adding `[]` "not work"? It should work!

Comment: Oddly nothing then nothing at all gets posted over. My PHP sessions page is just displaying the data that was displayed before I added `[]`

Comment: You may need to add `$_SESSION = array();` underneath `session_start();` @Byate since you're potentially dealing with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an array to hold these values, so `$array[] = $value` will append `$value` to the `$array`.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
     // Append POST data to SESSION
     $_SESSION['titles'][] = $_POST['title'];
}

print_r($_SESSION['titles']);
```

You don't need to make sure `$array` is actually an array, since `[]` will make the variable an array if needed: [`Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.`](https://www.php.net/array_push)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      session_start();
      if(isset($_POST['artist']))
   {
      $_SESSION['artist'][] = $_POST['artist'];
   }
     if(isset($_POST['title']))
   {
     $_SESSION['title'][] = $_POST['title'];
   }    

     print_r($_SESSION['artist']);
     echo "<br>";
     print_r($_SESSION['title']);
?>
```

user array to store it.